# Mi Jtable no carga información nueva y borra la que previamente cargue a la tabla en java Swing

Tags: java, java-swing

Amigos, un gusto saludarlos, tengo un problema al cargar múltiples archivos Json, lo que pasa es que cuando cargo un archivo si me agrega la primer fila al jtable hasta ahi todo bien, pero cuando repito el mismo proceso con otro archivo, este me quita el que cargué previamente, que es lo que podría estar sucediendo?

Este es mi código:

```
private void agregarValores(JSONObject json,Object[] row){//Nuevo parametro row 
        int cont = 0;
        DefaultTableModel modelo= (DefaultTableModel)miTabla1.getModel();  

             //modelo.addRow(row);//este agrega y repite la columna que cargue
             int rows = miTabla1.getRowCount();             
             modelo.insertRow(rows,  row);

             cont++;

            //miTabla1.setVisible(true); 
    }




//Metodo para extraer la información en el Json y pasarlo a un objeto
    private void obtenerMatriz(String jsonFile) {//JJ Metodo con el que estoy trabajando
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
         //Vector row = new Vector();//Nueva declaracion de vector
         Object[] objectVector = new Object[30];
         //String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
            //System.out.println("Fecha hoy..."+date);
        try{
            //Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader ( "D:/Usuarios/JBustamante/Desktop/C0_2019-05-31_927837_0.json"));    
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader (jsonFile));   
            System.out.println("Cadena completa json del archivo..." + obj);
            JSONObject jsonObjectArchivo = (JSONObject)obj;//se guarda en la variable jsonObject la cadena json del archivo
            JSONArray opcionesArray = (JSONArray)jsonObjectArchivo.get("opciones");
            JSONArray tipoEventosArray = (JSONArray)jsonObjectArchivo.get("tipoEventos");   

            objectVector[1] = jsonObjectArchivo.get("claveCotizacion");        
            objectVector[2] = jsonObjectArchivo.get("serie");


            Object quantity2 = jsonObjectArchivo.get("quantity2");
            if(quantity2==null){
                objectVector[5] = "quantity2_vacio";                
            }else{
                objectVector[5] = quantity2;
            }

            Object quantity1 = jsonObjectArchivo.get("quantity1");
            if(quantity1==null){
                objectVector[6] = "quantity1_vacio";                
            }else{
                objectVector[6] = quantity1;
            }

            objectVector[7] = jsonObjectArchivo.get("fechaExdate");//Poner validacion como arriba

            Object tipoEvento = jsonObjectArchivo.get("tipoEvento");
            if(tipoEvento==null){
                objectVector[3] = "tipoEvento_vacio";                   
            }else {
                objectVector[3] = tipoEvento;
            }

                //Recorremos en array, ya que sabemos su tamaño                 
                for(int i = 0; i< opcionesArray.size();i++){ //Recorrido de transacciones 

                    if(tipoEventosArray!=null){
                         for(int u = 0; u< tipoEventosArray.size();u++){//Recorrido de tipoEventos
                            JSONObject tipoEventosItem =(JSONObject) tipoEventosArray.get(u);
                             String qualifierDescription = (String)tipoEventosItem.get("qualifierDescription");
                             objectVector[23]= qualifierDescription;
                         }

                    }

                    JSONObject opcionesItem =(JSONObject) opcionesArray.get(i);
                    Long numero = (Long)opcionesItem.get("numero");
                    objectVector[21]= numero;



                    JSONArray transacciones = (JSONArray)(opcionesItem.get("transacciones"));                                      

                    for(int j = 0; j< transacciones.size();j++){
                        JSONObject transaccionesItem =(JSONObject)transacciones.get(j); 
                         String fechaPago =(String) transaccionesItem.get("fechaPago");
                         objectVector[8]= fechaPago;

                         JSONObject importeBruto =(JSONObject) transaccionesItem.get("importeBruto");
                         String currencyImporteBruto=(String)importeBruto.get("currency");
                         JSONObject importeNeto =(JSONObject) transaccionesItem.get("importeNeto");
                         if(importeNeto !=null){
                             String currencyImporteNeto=(String)importeNeto.get("currency");
                             objectVector[13]= currencyImporteBruto;
                             if(!currencyImporteBruto.equals(currencyImporteNeto)){
                                 objectVector[28]="Currency diferentes";
                             } 

                         }


                         JSONObject importeBrutoAmount =(JSONObject) transaccionesItem.get("importeBruto");
                         Double amountImporteBruto=(Double)importeBrutoAmount.get("amount");
                         JSONObject importeNetoAmount =(JSONObject) transaccionesItem.get("importeNeto");
                         if(importeNetoAmount !=null){
                             Double amountImporteNeto=(Double)importeNetoAmount.get("amount");
                             objectVector[22]= currencyImporteBruto;
                             if(amountImporteBruto<amountImporteNeto){
                                 objectVector[28]= "Importe Bruto Menor";                            
                             }

                         }


                        agregarValores(transaccionesItem, objectVector);
                    } 
                }

           // }        

        }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
```

Podría alguien indicarme que es lo que podría estar pasando? lo que en yo pienso es que es que el modelo se esté volviendo a inicializar con la información nueva que estoy cargando del json, espero y me puedan ayudar y brindarme tips de que podría estar causando este error, quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios, saludos y excelente tarde.

Answer (score 0):

Estás instanciando el DefaultTableModel dentro de un bucle y cada vez que se ejecuta esa línea está borrando y agregando la misma fila, intenta quitando la siguiente linea de codigo.

```
//QUITAR DE ESTE METODO LA INSTANCIA DEL MODELO
private void agregarValores(JSONObject json,Object[] row){//Nuevo parametro row 
    int cont = 0;

    // QUITAR ESTE
    DefaultTableModel modelo= (DefaultTableModel)miTabla1.getModel();  

         //modelo.addRow(row);//este agrega y repite la columna que cargue
         int rows = miTabla1.getRowCount();             
         modelo.insertRow(rows,  row);

         cont++;

        //miTabla1.setVisible(true); 
}

 //AGREGAR ANTES DEL DE ITERAR TRANSACCIONES (FOR)
 DefaultTableModel modelo= (DefaultTableModel)miTabla1.getModel();

 for(int j = 0; j< transacciones.size();j++){
 }
```

Comment: Hola Ever buenas tardes, el de for transacciones pertenece a otro metodo que es el de "obtenerMatriz" si lo pongo donde me dices mi modelo no será reconocido ya que lo acabo de hacer, saludos